DHCPv6 Not Working Ubuntu 24.04
I recently upgraded a few of my 22.04 VMs to 24.04. After the upgrade, getting an IP address via DHCPv6 is no longer functioning. I can get an IP address via SLAAC, but not DHCPv6. This was working before the upgrade, but each time I upgrade a VM, DHCPv6 no longer works.
